# CLLocationManager, delegate not getting called

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios6

I am very new to objective-c but I am playing around trying to learn as much as possible.

I need to call the CLLocationManager in a static class. I have been googeling around forever, but I don't understand how to set the delegate. Because this is a static class, I assume I need to create a new class and pass it though it.

**The static class:**

```
PositionManager *positionManage = [[PositionManager alloc] init];

CLLocationManager *locationManager = [[CLLocationManager alloc] init];
[locationManager setDelegate:positionManage];
locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest;
locationManager.distanceFilter = kCLDistanceFilterNone;
[locationManager startUpdatingLocation];
```

**PositionManager.h**

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import <CoreLocation/CoreLocation.h>

@interface PositionManager : NSObject <CLLocationManagerDelegate> {
    CLLocationManager *locationManager;
}

@property (strong, retain) CLLocationManager *locationManager;

@end
```

**PositionManager.m**

```
#import "PositionManager.h"

@implementation PositionManager

@synthesize locationManager;

- (id)init {
    self = [super init];
    NSLog(@"hei?");

    return self;
}

- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didUpdateLocations:(NSArray *)locations {
    // Never gets called...
}

@end
```

Comment: You should also implement `locationManager:didFailWithError:` and check to see if that is being called instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem appears to be that your PositionManager instance, which you call `positionManage`, comes into existence (`alloc-init`) and then goes right back out of existence again because you don't retain it anywhere.

(Actually, looking over your code, the same thing seems to be true of your CLLocationManager, which you call `locationManager`. You instantiate it but you don't retain so it vanishes instantly in a puff of smoke.)

So it might help you to stop and learn about how memory management works in Objective-C before "playing around".

Comment: This may sounds like a **stupid** question, but how would I do that? Mind updating your answer? I'll accept asap.

Comment: I've written an entire book that teaches you iOS programming. The memory management chapter is here: http://www.apeth.com/iOSBook/ch12.html But it seems to me that you might do well to start at the beginning. :)

Comment: Try adding Error delegate for CLLOcationManagerDelegate also. Firsly it might not work on simulator. By using device controller will come to error delegate method. TRy it. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

In your PositionManager class, you have field locationManager, but I don't see you assign actual instance to it. This might lead to fact that ARC destroys your instance of CLLocationManager as there is no object that has strong reference to it.

Try adding this:

```
positionManage.locationManager = locationManager;
```